# Maximum Accelerator Reading on Android

Tags: android, accelerometer

I want to detect if a device experiences shocks of up to +-16g (on Smartphones such as the Samsung Galaxy) using Android.

My understanding is that the sensor operates in a certain range, for example +-2g. What happens when the device is exposed to an acceleration that is beyond its current range, lets say 10g? Does the kernel automatically expand the range and calls the method onAccuracyChanged()?

Can I just rely on the fact that higher values will be measured? I found no public API to change the range of the accelerometer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess those sensors are typically not constructed for such acceleration, so they cannot measure such value and therefore, you cannot build such APIs.

But anyway, to be sure, you can write a simple App which displays/logs the current acceleration e.g. every 10 ms, and it's not too hard to produce >= 2g by hand (drop it on a table from ~ 50 cm and see what happens, if you dare... :P).